# Unread gunicorn POST request body

Tags: debugging, gunicorn

During debugging session I was trying to log POST data at gunicorn level, so I've defined pre_request hook.

```py
def pre_request(worker, req):
    if req.query.startswith('action') and req.method == 'POST':
        print(req.body) # (1)
        request = copy.deepcopy(req.body) # (2)
        print(request.read().decode())
```

After I tried the first approach, to print the body, after releasing execution i've got this error:

```
..lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 229, in should_close
    if self.status_code < 200 or self.status_code in (204, 304):
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'status_code'.
I suppose this is because the body buffer is empty.
```

When I've tried second approach: to copy deepbody I've got another problem:

```
..lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 272, in __getstate__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.__class__.__name__!r} object")
TypeError: cannot pickle 'socket' object
```

Then I've looked at gunicorn [source code](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/2bf26c1c86472b50508155a8ffde6c80e91099bc/gunicorn/http/body.py#L175) to see what's in this body object, but it's still not clear to me:

how to unreed the request body?

---

gunicorn==19.9.0
Flask==1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The deep copy creates independent copy of original object and all its nested objects. It makes socket object include Body caused pickle cannot serialize (socket type is outside the support types).

You can try:

```
def pre_request(worker, req):
    body_data = copy.copy(req.body)
    print(body_data.read().decode())
```

If your body request have file data, `utf-8` maybe error with decode some characters. use another such as latin-1

Comment: copy.copy resulted into the same error

Comment: @AlexBender what is your gunicorn version?. I worked wit gunicorn==20.1.0, Flask==2.2.2

Comment: a bit old; gunicorn==19.9.0, Flask==1.0.2